# partial encoder/decoder for ASN.1 unaligned PER

Tags: asn.1

to my understanding in ASN.1 UPER you may or may not have tag and length. in a nutt sell TL are omitted when ever possible and for that the ASN.1 compiler needs to know the entire ASN.1 code as to know if there are any ambiguities that require to add tag in order to solve them or in order to know what is the length of a structure including it sub structures.

Assuming my application uses only part of the ASN.1 code. does it still need to be able to encode/decode the entire ASN.1 code?

For example, lets say I am writing a c code encoder/decoder. The ASN.1 code  have a choice of 2 sequences, and my specific application (there are other applications in the same system) is expected to use only the first choice. it is obvious that my c code need to support a tag parsing to understand which of the sequences was sent but can my encoder/decoder "throw away" the part the  c code that handles the internal parsing of the 2nd sequence?

Comment: You seem to be asking, "Do I need to keep C code that I know will never execute?"  At least that is how I take your question.  The answer is obvious.

Comment: Well, the question is - am I missing something here with my ASN.1 understanding that would prevent me from deleting this code (since the code modeling I have described is not realistic)

Comment: You seem to have a correct understanding.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful.